# Why Android VM not use G1 Garbage Collector

Tags: android, garbage-collection, jvm

linked to https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview#gc, android current gc seems to be CMS.

with g1 benefit, why android not use g1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is based on a number of false premises:

1. Android does NOT use the OpenJDK CMS collector.  It has its own garbage collector.
2. The [page](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview#gc) that you linked to does NOT mention OpenJDK or CMS:

   - It does say that the Android GC is generational, but many, many collectors are generational.
   - It does NOT say that the Android collector is *concurrent*, which is one of the important characteristics of CMS and G1.
3. Android is NOT based on the OpenJDK codebase.  Therefore, the OpenJDK garbage collectors would not work in Android without (probably) a complete rewrite.
4. OpenJDK is covered by GPLv2 with the classpath extension, so the source code would technically be available to be ported.  However, the copyright remains with Oracle.  I cannot imagine Google wanting to incorporate any Oracle copyright code into the Android codebase.  (Especially given Oracle's unpleasant history of using litigation to gain a competitive advantage.)
5. The platform requirements for Android and OpenJDK are significantly different.  For example, OpenJDK is optimized for running services rather than apps.  The characteristics that make G1 attractive on a typical enterprise server are not necessarily a good match for an "app" running on someone's mobile phone, where (for example) there is less RAM and fewer cores, and power consumption / battery life are critical concerns.

In short, it doesn't make much sense for Android to support the G1 collector.  And it is unlikely that it will ever happen.

Comment: The decision to develop something new for Android was made when Sun was the Java owner and not only, Java wasn’t GPL back then, Sun’s business model was to get back from mobile device vendors what they were losing by giving away desktop versions for free. I don’t think that Oracle is relevant here. Things would have been entirely different if Java was GPLed right from the start.

Comment: It was Oracle that decided to sue Google, not Sun.  While things could have been different if Java had been open source from day 1, it was GPL'ed (by Sun!) before Oracle decided to sue.  The basis of the lawsuit was not copying the code.  (It was determined that the code copying was *de minimus*.) Instead, Google was found to have copied the API; i.e. the package, class and method **names**.

Comment: Google’s decision was made before that. The lawsuit was the result of the decision, not the other way round. I’m not defending Oracle, but they were just trying to keep Sun’s business model alive. Sun would have made that lawsuit already, if they weren’t running out of money for that. Obviously, the lawsuit was standing on a thin ground, as respecting someone else’s business model is nothing you can demand before a court. And given how much they failed, it’s unlikely that Google had to fear anything from using GPLed code from Java now. Not that it matters, as your third point still applies.

Comment: "Google’s decision was made before that." - Sure ... but that's not the decision that is at issue.  My point is that Oracle is *still* liable to *try* to make life difficult for Google ... if they could figure out a way to do it.  Software patents related to OpenJDK GC technology for example.  I know it is all "business".  But it sucks!

Answer (score 1):

The G1 garbage collector is a feature of the Oracle JVM, but Android does not use the Oracle JVM.  Furthermore, the G1 GC is unsuitable for mobile devices from a design standpoint which is likely a factor for why a similar algorithm wasn't implemented in the Android or Dalvik runtimes. From [this page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html):

> The Garbage-First (G1) collector is a server-style garbage collector, targeted for multi-processor machines with large memories.

Further, its memory overhead is higher, which is problematic for resource-constrained mobile devices:

> If you migrate from the ... CMS collector to G1, you will likely see a larger JVM process size. This is largely related to "accounting" data structures such as Remembered Sets and Collection Sets.

Comment: That article has been written for Java 7, a decade ago. By its standards, Android smartphones of today *are* “multi-processor machines with large memories”.